# BitBucket repository some folders not uploaded / clickable

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm a new user of BitBucket and also new with Git. In my project repository I use modules which are in separate folders. But some of this folders are not clickable, they only show the name with an arrow + number. Who can explain me what this means?

See:

[image]

Comment: It's called submodule.

Comment: Okay, but how can I push the whole code of this submodules to my repository? Why is it not pushed to my repository at BitBucket?

Comment: as u see, there're commit hash linked for the related submodule, thus for repos have those submodules no need to copy the code, only a reference needed, in this way, it saved lot disk space for server. For how to use submodule, u can search on web by urself, easy to use. ;)