# Pushed my project to my repos but didnt transfer the files and instead created some weird file

Tags: git, bitbucket

I selected my branch and did git push origin branchname and after it pushed to my repos I checked it on bitbucket and all of a sudden my folder for my visual studio project is now only 40 bites and its not even a folder.
[image]

It has a folder icon but I cant open it. Also theres now [da4e319fd55d] attached to it for some reason. The files on my computer are still normal and when I do git status it says its up to date. Ive tried pushing the project to it multiple times with no luck. I then created a new .txt outside of the folder. Did git push origin branchname and it appeared just fine.

Comment: Is the project a Git submodule? It seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235655/bitbucket-repository-some-folders-not-uploaded-clickable).

Comment: @ObsidianAge I guess it is. I dont know how it became a submodule but how do I remove/undo it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That folder is a submodule only if there is an associated `.gitmodules` in your repository.
If not, it is a gitlink, a reference to the root tree of a *nested* repository.

That means LaserTurret has a `.git` in it.

If you do not want this entry at all:

```
git rm --cache LaserTurret # no trailing slash
echo "LaserTurret/">>.gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "remove nested repo LaserTurret"
git push
```